# SQLAlchemy: How do I make a Model attribute refer to an entire Column in another table?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

This is the kind of model I can think of for a stock ticker database. I have two tables: `stocks`, whose primary key is `ticker`, and `prices`, whose primary key is `date`:

```
Table stock
ticker name          currency price
AAPL   Apple, Inc.   USD      <reference to column AAPL in prices>
GOOG   Google, Inc.  USD      <reference to column GOOG in prices>

Table prices
date        AAPL GOOG
2015-03-28  1.01 0.99
2015-03-29  1.02 0.97
2015-03-30  1.01 0.98
```

With a setup like that, I can lookup a stock's price history, or the prices of all stocks in a given day.

Inferring from the ORM tutorial, I am quite confident with how I might define the `Stock` model:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-python -->

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stocks'
    ticker        = Column(String)
    name          = Column(String)
    currency      = Column(String)
    price         = # Not sure about this
```

However, I am not sure how to model `prices`. I have already tried modelling a one-to-many relationship, but it does not catch what I want. I've read about many-to-many relationships, but it's not quite so either. How is it done? Or does that kind of data structure not fit into the ORM paradigm?

#### If it's not ORM at all ...

Another way I might model that relationship is to make the `Stock` instance callable:

```
class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stocks'
    ticker        = Column(String)
    name          = Column(String)
    currency      = Column(String)

    @decorator_that_indicates_database_session
    def __call__(self, start_date, end_date=None):
        # validate start_date and end_date here (for safety)
        s = 'SELECT {0} WHERE date >= {1} AND date <= {2} FROM prices'
        s = s.format(self.ticker, start_date, end_date)
        ret = session.execute(s)
        # Do stuff with `ret`
        return zip(dates, prices)
```

Comment: Do you use `sqlalchemy` to only read data, or will you also use it to write data?

Comment: @van I also use it to write data.

Comment: In this case I do not think that SA model is the best way to represent your data structure. Although not correct, a simple way to look at it is: each SA model *corresponds* to one *row* in the database. This is clearly not the case in your example. Also, how will you handle adding a new stock with ticker 'NEWZ'? You need to add a new column (a `DDL` operation), which is not supported by SA either.

Comment: @van Yes I was also concerned about adding new stock tickers. Do you mean SA == SQLAlchemy? Oh well, perhaps the ORM paradigm is not the best way to model my data.

Or maybe, I can use ORM to model `Stock`, but dive into low-level SQL queries when modelling the `prices` table.

Comment: Yes, SA==sqlalchemy. And how do you imagine you would *update price for APPL stock for a certain date (without doing anything with other stocks)*? Or inserting a new price for just one stock? Will in this case the other values be `NULL`?

Comment: @van, Yes, all other values will be `NULL`. They would be updated at a different time.

Comment: I really do not see any benefit of having a table design like this, which is violating the [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) principles anyways. Imagine you get 10'000 stocks. your search speed will not be great. You really should create a table `Prices (id pk, stock_id (fk:stock.id), date, price); plus unique constraint on `stock_id, date`.

Comment: @van, all right. I'll dig deeper into what you suggest. Still have a lot to learn. Thank you for the discussion!

Comment: How did you construct your "price" field? Float? Can you write an example? Thanks